# Action Script 3 - Check for stop commands in other frames

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm pretty new to action script, and I'm a little stumped on this problem. Basically on frame 1, I want to be able to find all of the frames in the animation that contain a stop command.

For instance, let's say there are stop commands on frame 3, 64, and 100.
I want to be able to search through the entire animation for stop commands, and return an array like this: [3, 64, 100]

Is that possible to do? I've tried searching a little but haven't been able to come up with anything.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you want to do with those frame numbers?

Comment: These frame numbers need to be stored into an array so they can be accessed by another program later on.
Right now I have to search through each animation for stop commands and create the arrays manually for each file. I'm just looking for a way to automate that process if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your best bet is to save the file containing the animation as an [xfl file that you can work with programmatically](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/documents.html#working_with_uncompressed_xfl_files)

As far as I remember, .fla files from CS5 onwards are just zip'ed .xfl files under the hood or something like that.

The point is that you get some text file based on XML that you can now search for whatever you want, including `stop()`. You can do this in pretty much any language you want as most languages are able conveniently parse and analyse XML files.